# Getting osascript applescript to untick checkbox finder extensions in system preferences

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, applescript, osascript

I have tried looking through many answered questions and wasn't able to fix my specific issue, the issue is telling applescript to look through Extensions in system preferences and untick this check box

I am unable to help applescript locate the checkbox through Extensions>Added Extensions>Core Sync>Finder Extensions, I'm not sure how to go about this.

I am able to open the extensions tab and have the checkbox the first thing that is infront, this is my code that does that:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal (pane id "com.apple.preferences.extensions")
end tell
```

[The checkbox im trying to untick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ymrE.jpg)

Comment: **Stack Overflow** is not a _code_ debugging/writing service. What have you tried? Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Big Sur** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

---

Since the target extension is the first one in the *list*, I've coded the *example* **AppleScript** *code* for that particular *checkbox*. Additional coding would be necessary to enumerate and target an extension by name.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
--  # Check to see if System Preferences is 
--  # running and if yes, then close it.
--  # 
--  # This is done so the script will not fail 
--  # if it is running and a modal sheet is 
--  # showing, hence the use of 'killall' 
--  # as 'quit' fails when done so, if it is.
--  #
--  # This is also done to allow default behaviors
--  # to be predictable from a clean occurrence.

if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

--  # Make sure System Preferences is not running before
--  # opening it again. Otherwise there can be an issue
--  # when trying to reopen it while it's actually closing.

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

--  # Open to the Extensions pane in System Preferences.

tell application "System Preferences" to ¬
    reveal pane id "com.apple.preferences.extensions"

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        --  # Wait until target UI element is available.        
        set i to 0
        repeat until ¬
            exists ¬
                checkbox 1 of ¬
                UI element 1 of ¬
                row 2 of ¬
                table 1 of ¬
                scroll area 1 of ¬
                group 1 of ¬
                window 1
            delay 0.2
            set i to i + 1
            if i ≥ 20 then return
        end repeat
        --  # Click the first checkbox.
        click ¬
            checkbox 1 of ¬
            UI element 1 of ¬
            row 2 of ¬
            table 1 of ¬
            scroll area 1 of ¬
            group 1 of ¬
            window 1
    end tell
end tell

delay 0.2

tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>